# Remove SMS from gammu outbox on send fail

Tags: raspberry-pi, gammu

I use gammu-smsd to send SMS from my rpi.

Sometimes the SMSC returns an unknown error for an SMS and this SMS blocks all other SMS ...
Example: my failed SMS in the outbox is OUTC20190409_165555_00_0781950085_sms0.smsbackup and all other SMS are waiting for it to be sent. So, all my SMS are blocked ...

Is there a way to remove the SMS from the Outbox if it fails to send?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Self-answer:

edit `/etc/gammu-smsdrc`

Add option `RunOnFailure = /var/spool/gammu/on-error.sh`

/var/spool/gammu/on-error.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /var/spool/gammu/outbox/$1 /var/spool/gammu/error
```